# Uninstall filemanager-actions

Tags: uninstall, menu, filemanager, nautilus-actions

I have done

```
sudo apt-get remove filemanager-actions
```

and

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus-actions
```

But I still have that **Filemanager-Actions actions** menu in my Nautilus menu. How to remove that menu item? I have logged out and in, and have restarted my laptop, but no use.

Comment: Please add the output of `dpkg -l | grep "\-actions"` to the question.

Comment: I am not sure why, but my problem got solved when my KDE apps were removed. I did "sudo apt remove libkf5*" and then"sudo apt autoremove". After I did that, my problem is gone.

Comment: @N0rbert Running dpkg -l | grep "\-actions" in terminal returned nothing. I am not sure why, but my problem got solved when my KDE apps were removed.

Answer (score -1):

U should not remove file manager

But If u want to remove it

1. sudo apt-get install filemanager
2. sudo apt-get purge filemanager
3. sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
4. sudo apt-get purge nautilus-actions

Comment: Thanks for the response. My problem got solved when my KDE apps were removed. I don't know why that happened. I have not tried your steps, though.